# How are numbers matched in OSM Nominatim Geocoder search?

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, osmdroid, nominatim

Here is one things that I cannot make sense of how Nominatim handles numbers (at least in Barcelona):

1. Searching for **Passeig de Gràcia** and appending numbers **38** or **1**, or **20** all returns the same set of results. I don't know where it's matching '38', or '1', or '20' because they are not in the [results](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&accept-language=en&addressdetails=1&limit=100&q=Paseo%20de%20gracia%2C%2020%20&viewbox=1.947302,41.500549,2.347807,41.264876&bounded=1) as fields.
2. Searching for **Calle Mare de Deu dels Desemparats 18** is not returning any result but removing **18** returns [1 result](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&accept-language=en&addressdetails=1&limit=100&q=Calle%20Mare%20de%20Deu%20dels%20Desemparats&viewbox=1.947302,41.500549,2.347807,41.264876&bounded=1).

Why does the service appear to be *lenient* to the number search parameters of **Passeig de Gràcia** while *strict* with **Calle Mare de Deu dels Desemparats**?

Comment: I'm afraid that you won't find an answer here. Try one of the following instead: Re-ask your question at http://help.openstreetmap.org/ (and mention this question here!), ask the developers directly or create a ticket at https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim

Comment: Thank you @scai, I've asked it in https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/44714/how-are-numbers-matched-in-osm-nominatim-geocoder-search